# Searching an array for an object's member variable

Tags: php, arrays, search, object

How would something like this be possible:

I have an object called Player:

```
class Player
{
  public $name;
  public $lvl;
}
```

and I have an array of these players in: $array.

For example `$array[4]->name = 'Bob';`

I want to search $array for a player named "Bob".

Without knowing the array key, how would I search $array for a Player named "Bob" so that it returns the key #? For example it should return `4`.

Would `array_search()` work in this case? How would it be formatted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will return you a new array with only the matching keys.

```
$playerName = 'bob';
$bobs = array_filter($players, function($player) use ($playerName) {
    return $player->name === $playerName;
});
```

Comment: If OP using PHP5.3 this is the way!

Comment: @Juicy For the unlucky, [`create_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) is always there.

Answer (score 1):

According to php [docs](https://www.php.net/array_search), array_search would indeed work:

```
$players = array(
    'Mike',
    'Chris',
    'Steve',
    'Bob'
);

var_dump(array_search('Bob', $players)); // Outputs 3 (0-index array)
```

-- Edit --

Sorry, read post to quick, didn't see you had an array of objects, you could do something like:

```
$playersScalar = array(
    'Mike',
    'Chris',
    'Steve',
    'Bob'
);

class Player
{
  public $name;
  public $lvl;
}

foreach ($playersScalar as $playerScaler) {

    $playerObject = new Player;

    $playerObject->name = $playerScaler;

    $playerObjects[] = $playerObject;
}    

function getPlayerKey(array $players, $playerName)
{
    foreach ($players as $key => $player) {
        if ($player->name === $playerName) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
 }

var_dump(getPlayerKey($playerObjects, 'Steve'));
```

Comment: It will not, since OP clearly stated that array is array of objects and not scalars...